# How to Iterate through the array of enums

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, loops

Im working on tictactoe 5x5 WPF application where I need to check for the buttons if they have the same mark as the buttons near them to check for the winner (2 to the left, 1 to right 1 to left, 2 to right).

There is a static array declared `mResults = new MarkType[25];`where `MarkType` is enum (free, nought, cross).

I'd like to iterate through an array of buttons (`mResults`) with each click, in function `Button_Click`.

I know one solution where basically you copy and paste this (approximately to the index) but it seems like too many ifs:

```
if (mResults[0] != MarkType.Free && (mResults[0] & mResults[1] & mResults[2]) == mResults[0])
{

   // game ends
   mGameEnded = true;

   // highlight winning cells in green
   Button0_0.Background =Button1_0.Background=Button2_0.Background=Brushes.Green;
}
```

Is there any possible way I can declare a function to iterate through an array `mResults` while i have declared `index` ?

```
var column = Grid.GetColumn(button);
var row = Grid.GetRow(button);
var index = column + (row * 5);`
```

I tried using (as an example) function `if` just for first three elements in the array `mResults` but it doesnt seem to work:

```
if (mResults[index] != MarkType.Free && (mResults[index] & mResults[index+1] & mResults[index+2]) == mResults[index])
{
   // game ends
   mGameEnded = true;

   // highlight winning cells in green
   Button0_0.Background = Button1_0.Background = Button2_0.Background = Brushes.Green;
}
```

Comment: While this is working in your specific case (assuming that "nought" has value 1 and "cross" has value 2), I caution you to look up the [`&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator#integer-logical-bitwise-and-operator) - it is a binary and, not a logical one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for a winning combination of 3 consecutive marks horizontally, vertically or diagonally is not difficult (which I believe is what you're after):

```
public enum MarkType
{
    Free = 0,
    Nought = 1,
    Cross = 2
}

private const int size = 5;
private readonly MarkType[] mResults = new MarkType[size * size];

public MarkType CheckWin()
{
    for (var x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            var offset = y * size + x;
            var mark = mResults[offset];
            if (mark == MarkType.Free)
            {
                // We don't do the checks when we are on a free mark
                continue;
            }

            if (x <= size - 3 && mark == mResults[offset + 1] && mark == mResults[offset + 2])
            {
                // Horizontal match at (x,y)..(x+2,y)
                return mark;
            }

            if (y <= size - 3 && mark == mResults[offset + size] && mark == mResults[offset + size * 2])
            {
                // Vertical match at (x,y)..(x,y+2)
                return mark;
            }

            if (x <= size - 3 && y <= size - 3 && mark == mResults[offset + (size + 1)] && mark == mResults[offset + (size + 1) * 2])
            {
                // Diagonal match at (x,y)..(x+2,y+2)
                return mark;
            }

            if (x <= size - 3 && y >= 2 && mark == mResults[offset - (size - 1)] && mark == mResults[offset - (size - 1) * 2])
            {
                // Diagonal match at (x,y)..(x+2,y-2)
                return mark;
            }
        }
    }

    return MarkType.Free;
}
```

However, coloring the buttons will be more difficult as long as you don't keep them in an array which matches the `mResult` array offsets. However, this was not part of the question so I leave it as exercise for you...